# Android - Using logo to be an dropdown list on ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How can I make the logo on ActionBar been an DropDown list, like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

But I want that this NavigationList is open from logo. Is any solution for this?

Comment: You shouldnt be doing this. The Logo on the ActionBar should only be used for "Up" and "Home" navigation.

Its not consistent with other Apps and the Standard Android Navigation and only confuses the User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely get rid of the icon and logo (e.g., `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()`), then use `setNavigationMode()` for your list.

Comment: But how can I create the elements for the list of logo menu? I used the Navigation_Mode_Standard, is that right? And then, how can I insert some items on that menu?

Comment: What I want is make a menu like number 2 on this pic http://developer.android.com/design/media/action_bar_basics.png

Comment: @DavidFortunato: Your code already does all of this. Have you actually tried running the code that you have in your question? If not, please do so. If you have, and the results are not what you want, please explain **in detail** what **specifically** is not coming out the way you want.

Comment: This is what are doing now: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/5124/device20120831153520.png But I want the logo be an menu, instead the "Test1".

Comment: @DavidFortunato: As I wrote in my answer, you can completely get rid of the icon and logo (e.g., `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()`), then use `setNavigationMode()` for your list. Then it is up to you to supply a `SpinnerAdapter` to `setListNavigationCallbacks()` that renders your menu how you want it, such as using icons instead of text, so you can have your logo there.

Comment: How can I set an icon on SpinnerAdapter to be show instead the items of the menu?

Comment: @DavidFortunato: Create your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter` (or whatever), change your `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item` to use `ImageView` instead of `TextView`, and override `getView()` on your `ArrayAdapter` to populate the `ImageView`. This is no different than the way you would put icons in a `ListView` or any other `AdapterView` (e.g., https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/Dynamic).

Comment: Finally I did it... Was like you said, but I didn't understand on the first time... Thank you very much for the answers.